# can I change 'turn off the display' time in a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to change  'turn off the display' time in a bat file.

Is it possible? I can change it manually.

I want to set the **value** to `Never`

You can see it below.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in [powercfg.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) can manage power settings/profiles/policies:

```
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
```

Comment: What is unit of "0"(or any value that can be provided for delaying the timeout) ?? Hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds ? Provide some meta-info too when answering so it could be useful for not just the original asker but also visitors.